# How to Create a custom maria DB docker image

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb

I am looking to create a docker image from maria DB . I need to set up my own build , create an Image and push to the registry. Can some one let me know what are the steps to be followed for the below ?

1. how to generate a build
2. What is required to build and image

for (1) I am using this link to create a build . Is this the right way ?

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/building-mariadb-on-ubuntu/

Thanks,
B

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You need Dockerfile to build your own docker image.
Please find the Dockerfile for mariadb version 10.3.
First download Dockerfile & entrypoint.sh from the official link

https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/tree/master/10.3

Run below command

```
docker build -t mariadb:10.3 .
```

This will build mariadb:10.3 image locally.